# Firebase storage : How to load images faster in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to fetch lots of images from firebase storage and display it in my flutter app but I am facing speed issues. It is taking a lot of time for the images to load. Also once the images are loaded they are loading again after I scroll down and scroll up. Is there any solution to this ?. This is my code.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WallpaperScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class WallpaperScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WallpaperScreenState createState() => _WallpaperScreenState();
}

class _WallpaperScreenState extends State<WallpaperScreen> {
  List<String> imageUrls = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchImages();
  }

  Future<void> fetchImages() async {
    try {
      final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .refFromURL("firebase url");
      final result = await storageRef.listAll();

      for (var item in result.items) {
        try {
          final url = await item.getDownloadURL();
          setState(() {
            imageUrls.add(url);
          });
        } catch (error) {
          print("Error fetching URL: $error");
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error fetching images: $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [
              Color(0xff0e0023),
              Color(0xff3a1e54),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 40),
            const Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Text(
                'Wallpapers',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: imageUrls.length,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 9 / 16,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 30,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 30,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => FullScreenImageScreen(
                                imageUrl: imageUrls[index],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Image.network(
                          imageUrls[index],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                              ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                            if (loadingProgress == null) {
                              return child;
                            } else {
                              return Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes !=
                                          null
                                      ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                          loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                                      : null,
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```